IMO 1989 Problem 6

Does the formula $(2n)!-(2n-2)!⋅(n-1)⋅4$ hold for all $n\in\Bbb N$ such that it gives the value of the number of permutations of the set $\{1,2,\ldots, 2n\}$ with the property $P$ (the difference between one or more pairs of adjacent values in a permutation of the set is equal to $n$)?

I’ve only tried it for $n=2$ and $3$, as $1$ is trivial. But I obtained this formula by letting any two numbers with property $P$ be a letter. Such as $1$, $3$ be $A$, and $2$, $4$ be $B$ for $n=2$, obtaining sets $\{A,2,4\}$ and $\{B,1,3\}$, and list their permutations and subtracting the overlapping permutations (such as $AB$ and $BA$). Since I have $2$ sets, I have $3!\times 2$ and I multiply it by $2$ again as $1$, $3$ and $3$, $1$ have the same difference. Same with the overlapping permutations, $2!\times 2\times 2$ as $2!$ From $\{A,B\}$, $2\times 2$ from the number of opposite pairs ($13$ and $31$).
For $n=3$, I let $1$, $4$ be $A$. $2$, $5$ be $B$. $3$, $6$ be $C$. So I have sets $\{A,2,3,5,6\}, \{B,1,3,4,6\}$ and $\{C,1,2,4,5\}$. As I have $3$ sets, I have $5!\times 3$ and $\times 2$ again as opposite pairs ($14$ and $41$). I then looked at another set $\{A,B,3,6\}$ and I have $4!$, and $\{A,C,2,5\}$, so $4!\times 2$, and $\times 2\times 2$ as there are $2$ sets of $2$ different opposite pairs which have property $P$. So $(5!\times 3\times 2)-(4!\times 2\times 2\times 2$)
Edit: I have looked at $n=4$, and the formula seems to be $(2n)!-(2n-2)!\cdot(n-1)\cdot4$

What have you tried?

@JoshS It's better to put this in your post by clicking the Edit button.

I suggest 1/ Using all letters $A, A, B, B, C, C, ... N, N$. The $2^n$ refers to choosing which $A = 1, n+1$. 2/ Applying Principle of Inclusion and Exclusion to count.
